# DRCSIM: Atlas URDF glitches

Tags: gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

1. Torque limits on leg_uhz are not the same: 110 vs 260

/usr/share/drcsim-2.3/ros/atlas_description/urdf/atlas.urdf

```
<joint name="l_leg_uhz" type="revolute">
    <origin xyz="0 0.089 0" rpy="0 -0 0" />
    <axis xyz="0 0 1" />
    <parent link="pelvis" />
    <child link="l_uglut" />
    <dynamics damping="0.1" friction="0" />
    <limit effort="110" velocity="12" lower="-0.32" upper="1.14" />

<joint name="r_leg_uhz" type="revolute">
    <origin xyz="0 -0.089 0" rpy="0 -0 0" />
    <axis xyz="0 0 1" />
    <parent link="pelvis" />
    <child link="r_uglut" />
    <dynamics damping="0.1" friction="0" />
    <limit effort="260" velocity="12" lower="-1.14" upper="0.32" />
```

2. As long as we are cleaning up the model.
   l_lglut:ixy and r_lglut:ixy should have opposite signs, same for lglut:iyz,
   uglut:ixy, uglut:iyz, lleg:ixz, hand:ixz
3. These links have no inertial fields, so the default mass and moi need to be zero.

```
link name="right_palm_left_camera_optical_frame"
link name="right_palm_right_camera_optical_frame"
link name="left_palm_left_camera_optical_frame"
link name="left_palm_right_camera_optical_frame"
link name="left_camera_optical_frame"
link name="right_camera_optical_frame"
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2320/drcsim:-atlas-urdf-glitches/) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2013-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

For questions 1 and 2, there's a [pull request](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/pull-request/191).  Some of the moi signs had already been fixed, but a couple had not.  Thanks for finding those!

For question 3, those frame just don't factor into simulation.  They have no mass, inertia, or other physical properties.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yohei Kakiuchi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/170/yohei-kakiuchi/) on 2013-05-19**:
This problems have fixed in source files. But, atlas.urdf and `atlas_sandia_hands.urdf` in debian package (drcsim2.6.1) still remain. ex. `effort_limit of r_leg_uhz` is 260.